# how to have a horizontal pane at the bottom in vim showing recent commands

Tags: vim

I usually work in vim with two panes split vertically with NERDTree being on left. I run external commands with `:!` and `ESC` out when the command is completed. Sometimes I want to run the same command again so I have to do `:<up arrow>enter`

To avoid this, I want to know if there is a way to have a horizontal pane at the bottom of the page that shows the last 5 external commands. In addition, it would be awesome if I can, for example, run the last `4th` command by simply doing `:!4` or something similar.

Comment: Do you know about the [command-line window](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/cmdline.html#cmdline-window)?

Comment: No! I didn't know however sometimes while saving and exiting files in a rush I had seen that window but could never get it back. Now it figures that I probably typed `q:` in normal mode by mistake. Still would like to know how to execute the last `N'th` external command.

Comment: The only problem is that you can't apparently leave it open, though opening it is not that difficult. And sorry, but I can't remember any way of running the nth last external command. Only `:!!`, for the last one, if it helps :-)

Comment: To execute the command from 3 commands ago:  `q:3k<cr>`  You can make a little function or macro to do it for you, but in the end I don't think it's going to save many keystrokes, there are only 5 keystrokes in sequence above to begin with.  Vim is great but it can't read your mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you know about:

`@:` - repeat last command

`q:` - list of commands from history, you can edit and run them.

To run Nth last command from history use this:

```
command! -nargs=1 H call histdel("cmd", -1) | execute histget("cmd", 0-<args>)
```

`:H 4` - last 4th command

Comment: That command seems like a step backwards from using built-in of `q:4k<cr>`.  For one thing, it doesn't save any keystrokes.  And it's worse in two ways: (1) It increases complexity by adding yet another command to remember, and (2) It doesn't give you a chance to see the command history before choosing which one you want.